# How to populate table's row of Parent component from child component data in Angular 4 with correct style?

Tags: angular

I am trying to populate the tables row with the data from Child component. Though the data is populated but the format is not correct. All the value in row goes under a single column instead of spreading equally.   
Please guide to achieve it. Thanks!!! Below is code. PS: I have imported all required Modules/Classes.

*mro-item-list.component.ts*

```
export class MroItemListComponent implements OnInit {
    mockMROItems: Mro[] = MRO_ITEMS;
    index: number;
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

*mro-item-list.component.html*

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#Index</th>
    <th>Ticket Number</th>
    <th>Activity</th>
    <th>comments</th>
    <th>Date</th>        
    <th>Portfolio</th>
    <th>UserID</th>
    <th>Hrs</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<app-mro-item *ngFor="let mockMROItem of mockMROItems"   [mroElement]="mockMROItem"></app-mro-item>           
</tbody>
```

*mro-item.component.ts*

```
export class MroItemComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() mroElement: Mro;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { }
}
```

*mto-item.component.html*

```
<th>Index</th>
<td>{{mroElement.tickteNumber}}</td>
<td>{{mroElement.activity}}</td>
<td>{{mroElement.comments}}</td>
<td>{{mroElement.date}}</td>
<td>{{mroElement.portfolio}}</td>
<td>{{mroElement.userID}}</td>
<td>{{mroElement.hrsSpent}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tbody` is supposed to contain `tr` elements, not `app-mro-item` elements.

Use `<tr app-mro-element ...` and set the selector of your component to `[app-mro-element]`.