# Angular problem in returning data in component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the child's result in the parent Html. The parent worked, and the child worked too, but I have a problem in showing the result in the Html parent.
I send my model to the child, the child processes my data, and returns the values correctly.

```
<div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="listPro?.length > 0">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <!--<th jhiSortBy="departureDate"><span jhiTranslate="transporterApp.passenger.departureDate">Departure Date</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>-->
        <th><span>Name</span></th>
        <th><span>Rate</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let p of listPro">
        <jhi-home-product-list [esm]="p"></jhi-home-product-list>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

jhi-home-product-list Html

```
<td>{{esm.name}}</td><td>{{esm.avg}}</td>
```

[image: result]

but I need to get this result:

[image: correct result]

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of listPro" jhi-home-product-list = p><tr>
```

Also, this is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518394/how-to-populate-tables-row-of-parent-component-from-child-component-data-in-ang).